# Receiving error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string' when I try to run this dropdown list

Tags: c#, string, list, drop-down-menu, compiler-errors

I am very new to C#, and got thrown into it by the company that I work for, so I apologize for my extreme lack of knowledge on all of this. The site uses a dropdown list so the user can select a language to view the site in. This is the code that I started with, which worked perfectly.

```
protected void CreateLanguageList()
{
    // Get the available cultures.
    string[] cultures = Telerik.Localization.Configuration.ConfigHelper.Handler.Cultures.Split(',');

    foreach (string availableCulture in cultures)
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(availableCulture.Trim());
        var item = new ListItem(culture.NativeName, culture.ToString());
        LanguageSelector.Items.Add(item);

        if (culture.ToString() == currentCultureString)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we are migrating to an updated CMS, Telerik.Localization is no longer supported. After contacting their support, they said that I could access the language files by using this code and accessing the name of the culture using the DisplayName() property:

```
var allCultures = AppSettings.CurrentSettings.AllLanguages.ToList();
```

Due to my very limited lack of knowledge on C# so far (I am trying to teach myself), I didn't want to change the code too much if I didn't have to, so I found where I could convert a list to a string, which i figured would allow me to leave the rest of the code alone, only having to change the one call to the language files. However, I am receiving a CS0030 error when I try and run this code:

```
protected void CreateLanguageList()
{
    // Get the available cultures.
    var allCultures = AppSettings.CurrentSettings.AllLanguages.ToList();
    string combinedCultures = string.Join(",", allCultures);

    foreach (string availableCulture in combinedCultures)
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(availableCulture.Trim());
        var item = new ListItem(culture.NativeName, culture.ToString());
        LanguageSelector.Items.Add(item);

        if (culture.ToString() == currentCultureString)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help in explaining what I'm doing wrong and how I could go about fixing it would be monumentally appreciated.

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: The log file states the line with the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `combinedCultures` is defined as a string, but then you're trying to iterate over it with a type string in the foreach. When you iterate over a string you get chars. You should be able to just get rid of the `combinedCultures` variable altogether and foreach using  `allCultures`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I tried that, it gave me this error, any thoughts?

Comment: error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,System.Globalization.CultureInfo>' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that foreach is only working on `availableCulture` because the type `string` is implicitly an array of `char`.

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but it looks like you're turning an array into a string when you just need to pass the array in directly.